# Monitor Multiple Global NSEventMask

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, swift, cocoa

I want to listen to multiple global events fired at same time. For my example to the `LeftMouseDraggedMask` and at the same time to `KeyDownMask`.
My first opinion was to add these by `&` operator.

`NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask(NSEventMask.LeftMouseDraggedMask & NSEventMask.KeyDownMask, handler: { (event: NSEvent!) -> Void in ... })`

The `LeftMouseDraggedMask` worked properly, but there was no effect with both.
I recognized that the `KeyDownMask` only works in the LocalMonitor. Help (:

Answer (score 0):

Okay the problem is that the Application have to be a assitance Device in OSX under Systemsettings > Security > Assistence to use `KeyDownMask`!